# php search folders with specific pattern in the name

Tags: php, regex

Environment: Windows 7 + XAMPP for Windows 5.6.15

I need to search a folder for sub-folders that match one of the pattern from these two

- `E*.mysoftware.swl.px64`
- `E*.r*.mysoftware.swl.px64`

So these are the set of sub-folders I need to select

```
E0234.mysoftware.swl.px64
E0235.mysoftware.swl.px64
E0236.mysoftware.swl.px64
E0236.r2.mysoftware.swl.px64
E0237.mysoftware.swl.px64
E0237.r2.mysoftware.swl.px64
E0237.r3.mysoftware.swl.px64
```

These shouldn't select

```
E0237.A.mysoftware.swl.px64
E0237.b3.mysoftware.swl.px64
```

My question is can I do this search by using only one pattern?

Comment: Yes, you will have to make `r*` part optional like I did in this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tD5tW2/1). Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: are you using `regex` or [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)?

Comment: I uses `GlobIterator`

Comment: `glob("E*.r*.mysoftware.swl.px64")` and recurse it for folders [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is make the `.r*` part optional which I have done using the following regex.

**Regex:** `E\d*(\.r\d*)?\.mysoftware\.swl\.px64$`

**Flags used:**

- `g` for global search.
- `m` for multi-line search.

**Explanation:**

- `(\.r\d*)?` this makes the `.r*` part optional, thus facilitating searches of both patterns in one regex.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD5tW2/3)**</kbd>

Comment: This is near to my requirement. but this matches `E0236.mysoftware.swl.px64_test` . is there a way to avoid?

Comment: So you don't want to match string with `_text` in the end ? Are there more rules to be followed ?  I have edited my answer to fit your recent rule.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(E[\w]+.mysoftware.swl.px64)|(E[\w]+.r[\w]+.mysoftware.swl.px64)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qG4iT4/1

Hope this helps.